# Displaying Inner joined table has different values in 1 column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Hello! I need help i have table that has this value**

```
Table1
sorter | valuedata | status   | useraccounts |
----------------------------------------------
 same  |  value1   | Disabled |    user1     |
 same  |  value2   | Active   |    user1     |
```

**And**

```
Table2
name     | useraccounts | 
-------------------------
user1    | displayname1 |
```

and I wanted to display all the data even they have different status while they are innerjoin like this

```
SELECT table1.name,table2.useraccounts 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.useraccounts = table2.name 
WHERE table1.sorter = "same" AND table1.status = "Disabled" AND table1.status != "Disabled"
```

is this even possible to do??

Comment: What kind of output are you looking to get? Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You don't need 'AND table1.status = "Disabled" AND table1.status != "Disabled" since that bascially means everything. Also, you have table1.name, is this correct or a typing error?

Comment: When you use this : table1.status = "Disabled" AND table1.status != "Disabled" , you never get result.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need the cross join. You can write it without using the JOIN as well:

```
SELECT table2.name,table2.useraccounts 
FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.useraccounts = table2.name 
AND table1.sorter = "same"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made 2 mistakes:

1. table 1 does not have name column
2. what you are look for is an OR instead of AND.

The next is what I think you are looking for:

```
SELECT table2.[name],table2.useraccounts 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.useraccounts = table2.name 
WHERE table1.sorter = 'same' AND 
(table1.status = 'Disabled' OR table1.status != 'Disabled')
```

and this can be rewritten to the next since checking for 'Disabled' or != 'Disabled' is ALL ROWS.

```
SELECT table2.[name],table2.useraccounts 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.useraccounts = table2.name 
WHERE table1.sorter = 'same'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table2.name,table1.useraccounts 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.useraccounts = table2.name
```

U will get all data while status is differnt or not